# flutter reactive ble taking long to read data from device

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

I am using flutter reactive ble by Philips Hue everything is working fine but when i am sending the request to the device to fetch the data it takes total of 8-10 seconds to fetch a single data idk why but it is fetching the data fast sometimes from 1 to 29

The task i am doing is i am fetching the data length first and then sending the signal to the device to send the next row then after every fetching i need to notify the device that i've read the data send the next row apart from this i am saving it into sqflite database and fetching it.

Here is the code sample

```
Future<int> getHistoryDataLength(String deviceId) async {
    final data = await automatServices.requestHistoryDataSize(deviceId);
    // log(int.parse(data.toString()).toString());
    print(int.parse(data));
    return int.parse(data);
  }

  Future<String> getHistoryData(String deviceId) async {
    final data = await automatServices.requestedHistoryData(deviceId);
    return data;
  }
  //
  Future<String> getHistoryReady(String deviceId) async {
    final data = await automatServices.readHistoryReady(deviceId);
    print(data);
    return data;
  }

  Future getCountAndInsertData(String deviceId)async{
    await _dbHelper.init();
    final d = await getHistoryDataLength(deviceId);
    historyDataLength.value = d;
    for (var i = 1; i <= historyDataLength.toInt();i++) {
      print("$i entered loop");
      final historyReady = await getHistoryReady(deviceId);
      print("time took history ready");
      isHistoryReady.value = historyReady;
      if (isHistoryReady == "1") {
        final historyData = await getHistoryData(deviceId);
        print("get data");
        print(historyData);
        await automatServices.writeHistoryDone(deviceId, [50]);
        _sendNotification(historyData);
        HistoryTable model =
        HistoryTable(i,deviceId,historyData.toString());
        await _dbHelper.addItem(model);
      }
      print(_dbHelper.fetchHistory().asStream().length);
    }
  }
```

Here are the methods of service class

```
 Future<String> requestHistoryDataSize(String deviceId) async {
    List<int> list = [];
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(await flutterReactiveBle.readCharacteristic(qualifiedChar(
        Uuid.parse(ServiceIds.REQUEST_HISTORY_DATA_SIZE), deviceId)));
    log("----REQUEST_HISTORY_DATA_SIZE----" + list.toList().toString());
    log("----REQUEST_HISTORY_DATA_SIZE----" + convertAscii(list).toString());
    print("request data" + convertAscii(list).toString());

    return convertAscii(list).toString();
  }

  Future<String> requestedHistoryData(String deviceId) async {
    List<int> list = [];
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(await flutterReactiveBle.readCharacteristic(qualifiedChar(
        Uuid.parse(ServiceIds.REQUESTED_HISTORY_DATA), deviceId)));
    log("----REQUESTED_HISTORY_DATA----" + list.toList().toString());
    log("----REQUESTED_HISTORY_DATA----" + convertAscii(list).toString());
    print("requested"+convertAscii(list).toString());

    return convertAscii(list).toString();
  }

  Future<String> readHistoryReady(String deviceId) async {
    print("reading");
    List<int> list = [];
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(await flutterReactiveBle.readCharacteristic(
        qualifiedChar(Uuid.parse(ServiceIds.HISTORY_WRITE_DONE), deviceId)));
    print("dones //////////////////////////////////");
    log("----Read history done----" + list.toList().toString());
    log("----Read history done----" + convertAscii(list).toString());

    return convertAscii(list).toString();
  }

  Stream<String> readHistoryReadyStream(String deviceId) async* {
    List<int> list = [];
    while (deviceId.isNotEmpty) {
      await Future.delayed(
        const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
        () async {
          list.clear();
          list.addAll(await flutterReactiveBle.readCharacteristic(qualifiedChar(
              Uuid.parse(ServiceIds.HISTORY_WRITE_DONE), deviceId)));
          log("----Read history done----" + list.toList().toString());
        },
      );
      yield convertAscii(list).toString();
    }
  }

  Future<void> writeHistoryDone(String deviceId, List<int> value) async {
    try {
      await flutterReactiveBle.writeCharacteristicWithoutResponse(
          qualifiedChar(Uuid.parse(ServiceIds.HISTORY_WRITE_DONE), deviceId),
          value: value);
      log("done--------");
    } catch (e) {
      log("error-------" + e.toString());
    }
  }



  getHistoryDataAsStream(
      String value, Box<HistoryModel> dataBox, String id) async {
    if (value == "1") {
      logg.log("<-----value-----$value---------->");

      // /// write history done as 3 i.e. 51.
      //writeHistoryDone(id, [51]);

      /// check history data exits in DB
      if (dataBox.values.isEmpty) {
        // final user = await dataBox.values.firstWhere((element) {
        //   return element.deviceId == id;
        // });
        // Logger? logger;
        // logger!.i(user.key);

        /// if history data does not exits in DB
        // if (user.key == null) {
        /// add for once the history empty data into DB for the key
        List a = [];
        //List a = [{0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 5, 5: 3, 6: 5, 7: 3, 8: 5, 9: 3, 10: 1, 11: 3, 12: 2, 13: 4, 14: 5, 15: 3, 16: 6}];
        HistoryModel data = HistoryModel(deviceId: id, historyData: a);
// dataBox.clear();
        dataBox.add(data);
      } else {
        /// update the data into the DB if already user exits.
        final user = dataBox.values.firstWhere((element) {
          return element.deviceId == id;
        });
        final previousHistoryList = user.historyData;
        final historyData = await requestedHistoryData(id);
        final dataToAdd = historyData.split("").asMap();
        previousHistoryList.add(dataToAdd);
        logg.log("<---user--key---${user.key}-------->");


        HistoryModel model =
            HistoryModel(deviceId: id, historyData: previousHistoryList);

        final dataMap = dataBox.toMap();
        dynamic selectedKey;

        dataMap.forEach((key, value) {
          if (value.deviceId == id) {
            logg.log("<----key------${key}---->");

            /// logger!.i(key.toString());
            selectedKey = key;
          }
        });

        await dataBox.put(user.key, model);
        logger!.i("Data has been added to DB!");
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Added");

        writeHistoryDone(id, [50]);
      }
    } else {
      // writeHistoryDone(id, [49]);
      logg.log("<---the value of read is not 1----------->");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:

1. Right after connecting to a device, try to set a higher value for MTU. Maybe you're trying to read a big data package that the current setting doesn't supports.
2. Use nRF Connect by Nordic to validated if your device is sending data as expected. There you can see every characteristic available as well as logs and debug tools, 'tis pretty helpful.

Hope it helps you somehow.